401k Calculation Accuracy
Here's the formula I'm working with for forecasting my 401k:

where t is in years, P(0) denotes starting principal, r denotes average annual rate of return, and c_i denotes biweekly contributions I make to the 401k (indexed by i because I could imagine a world where my contributions increase as I get older/paid more hopefully).
Example: Suppose I start with 75k already saved up and contribute 1k biweekly, then if we have a strong(ish) bull market w/ 10% average returns (pretend for a second), then I end up with approximately 620k after 10 years.
Question: Does this make sense or is it overly optimistic? I wonder how other people forecast their rate of return and if the yearly to monthly conversion makes sense or not for the 401k calculation w/o adding any stochastic elements.

One of the biggest factors here is inflation. I would recommend to either adjust the  effective rate of return or build it explicitly into your model

It's perfectly fine for a forecast - 10% seems a bit optimistic but you can try different rates and see how different the end results are.
Accuracy is not the goal - there's no way to accurately predict what the market will do in the future. The best you can do is "plan for the worst, but hope for the best". The market is not a true "random walk" even though it's modeled that way. Human behavior plays way too big of a part for it to be truly random.
Increasing your contribution over time is a very good addition - as your salary increases your retirement contribution should increase also.
Adding the stochastic elements would not change your expected end value, but it would give you a distribution of possible results with the expected result being the most likely (the "high point" on the bell curve).
So it depends on what your goal is - if you just want some sort of indication of how much you need to save to reach a certain goal.
So all in all it's a great start. The bottom line is to start saving early and not worry too much about how accurate your rate ofd return is - that will likely take care of itself over time.  Some incremental improvements that you can make over time:

Add your "stochastic" elements to get a more probabilistic analysis - what's the worst case you can live with? What's the probability that you will be below that?
If you want a simpler model that a stochastic model, just look as "best" and "worst" cases. What if your actual rate of return is 5%? What is the minimum rate of return that will meet your retirement goals?
Consider tax consequences - should you invest in traditional or Roth accounts, or non-tax-sheltered?
Are there other types of "savings" that you should consider in addition to retirement? College savings? Medical savings?

Lastly, I would posit that your behavior is a much bigger factor than any of these forecasts. The more you save, the less you spend, and the less you borrow, the better off you'll be.
